# How to go about duplicating a panel of controls dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an application that has is using an `asp:panel` that has 2 labels, 2 link buttons, a droplist and a textbox to collect and display information back to the user. Here is an example:

```
[panel]
[droplist (choose med - fed by xml file)/] 
[label (auto populates med min and max)/] [textbox (user enters quantity)/]
[linkbutton(add another panel for additional item)] [linkbutton(remove current item)]
[/panel]
```

[image]

I tried doing this by duplicating each control individually with the use of for loops and it got really complicated. There has got to be an alternative to doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184149/how-do-i-create-a-table-with-my-dynamically-created-textboxes/) other than creating a ton of panels and making them visible/invisible on link click.

Answer (score 0):

How do you wish to duplicate them? It may be possible for you to put the control within an ascx file and then declare it within your web config in the following manner

```
<controls>
      <add tagPrefix="Controls" tagName="YourControl" src="~/_assets/usercontrols/yourcontrol.ascx />
</controls>
```

you could then use this control as you would anything else

```
<Controls:YourControl />
```

If this isn't what you meant please let me know in detail and I'll have another look.

Edit: After reading your post again, it seems like you may wish to look at the Listview control.

Comment: So create the panel as a user control then use a for loop to add the control dynamically?

Comment: You could very well do this yeah :)